# Jquery Codes for ellipsis and Highlighting words at the results when you enter a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a webpage. I have 2 problems

**First one** is, I want to have "ellipsis(...)" whenever the user input more than 10 characters. Here's my codes Jquery codes

```
$("#input").bind("keypress keydown", function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#results").text($("#input").val());
},0);
```

});

Here's my html tags

```
Enter Character here: <input type="text" id="input">
Search Results: <input type="text" id="search">
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Second one** is, I want to have highlight the words that match on the search input that I've created. Just like in google search. Whenever you've entered a keyword, it will highlight those keyword on the search results.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/gm4k3hbe/

Comment: What is the exact function of setTimeout in the first code? And I think the code you provided is just for UI. You want us to think the logic and write the programming code for you? How about showing us what you've done first. May be we can improve your solution by providing extra opinions.

Comment: @ilter have you seen my jsfiddle? :)

Comment: Yes, I was talking about you fiddle :)

Comment: That's all I can make @ilter. Do you have any idea about my problem?